# MYSQL Putting Option Menu in One Table

Tags: mysql

Is it necessary to put all the option menu like status, civil status, gender and kind of status that answerable by boolean or 0-9 in one TABLE only. Or Is it necessary to separate them in different tables like table_civil_status, table_gender, and the like....

Comment: You really need to provide a lot more information about what you are trying to do if you want a clear answer. this totally depends on how these items relate to one another as well as to other object in your system.

Answer (score 0):

The question isn't how many tables you have.  The question is what are the entities that the database represents.

From your question, it would seem that you have a `person` entity, that has various information about a person.  In this case, it would make sense to put all the attributes about a person in one table.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like most of a data can be placed in 1 table, but you need additional tables for smth like civil_status and other options that you usually displays as selectbox. In main table you should have a foreign key to that tables